# JQuery datatables ajax sends the data but action method receives null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a JQuery datatables code which is working in an old-school ASP.Net MVC project. However I couldn't make it work in .Net Core 3.1. I tried almost every possible way but in best case I get null input in action method from the Ajax request. I logged the data in Ajax post method and it looks correct in the browser console.

This is the action method in my old project that works:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
string req = Request.Form[0].ToString();
...
}
```

This is the Ajax in my old project Datatables that works:

```
 "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": url,
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.searchParam = $('#srcParam').val();
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            }
```

I don't know the equivalent of "Request.Form[0] in .Net Core which can catch the data without an input parameter. In my new project I used same Ajax but i always get null value coming into my action method's input parameter. I tried many possible fixes including below but nothing worked:

-Adding `[HttpPost]` attribute to my action method

-Adding `contentType: "application/json"` to my ajax

-Using ajax `type: "GET"` instead.

-Naming my data in ajax `data: { data: JSON.stringify(@Model.CityId) },` and having same name input parameter as "data" in my action method.

-Adding `[FromBody]` and `[FromForm]` attributes to my action method input parameter.

-Tried to send data with and without `JSON.stringify`

At this point I am lost and don't know how to get this data. For the reference current state of the code i have in my current project is below:

Action method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetBusRouteList([FromBody]string data)
{
   string req = data;
}
```

Ajax

```
"ajax": {
         "type": "POST",
         "url": url,
         "dataType": "json",
         "contentType": "application/json",
         "data" : { data: JSON.stringify(@Model.CityId) }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your datatable ajax and action like this:

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetBusRouteList(string data)
{
   string req = data;
}
```

Ajax:

```
"ajax": {
         "url": url,
         "data" : { "data": '@Model.CityId' }
        }
```

You can also refer to the examples of the [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)

Update:
replace 'Request.Form[0].ToString();' in ASP .Net Core

```
var dict = HttpContext.Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: I already tried this combination. I get this error in Browser console: "XML Parsing Error: no root element found" 
and also this error from Datatables:  http://datatables.net/tn/7  which says "server responds with anything other than 2xx status code". My request doesn't hit the action method in this case.

Comment: You can try `var dict = HttpContext.Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());` to replace `Request.Formxxx;`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much Yiyi You. I was looking for this Request.Form thing since some time on the internet but couldn't find it. I am marking this as answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below:

Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetBusRouteList([FromBody]int data)
{
   string req = data.ToString();
}
```

Ajax:

```
"ajax": {
     "type": "POST",
     "url": url,
     "dataType": "json",
     "contentType": "application/json",
     "data" : JSON.stringify(@Model.CityId),
    }
```

Comment: This one doesn't send the @Model.CityId. So i get the input as 0. Also even if it did then how can i access other Datatables related parameters like draw, length, order and start ? Is there actually an equivalent of Request.Forms[0] in .Net Core ? If i have such option then my problem should be solved. I tried Request.Forms("formName") thing but it didn't work.